# viewing data from harddrive in windows 7

Tags: encryption, cmd, window, directory, hard-drive

I have installed [folder](http://www.newsoftwares.net/folderlock/) lock to protect my Drive and lock it , once it locks my drive and I goto properties I saw something like this
[image]

once you unlock the drive you get all the data back .
unfortunately the software is no more allowing me to unlock the drive,Since the data is inside the hard drive , is their any way to get the data through any means?
I tried even through command prompt but couldn't get that done. 
please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goto Computer Management

then click on Disk Management

Right clik on the Drive and change its letter

BINGO you are done.

There is a big flaw in this software it works on drive NAME

so if your drive is D , change it to E and you will get your data back
Cheers

Comment: I can't believe that software is that stoopid either.  In normal cases an encrypted drive is next to impossible to recover.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but no. If the encryption software is even remotely competent, it will be mathematically "difficult" (which is a major understatement) to access your data. Your best bet is to restore from backup.

**Update:** So Folder Lock isn't actually a security problem at all. Ok then! But take this as an easy lesson: *start making backups today*. Think of all the stuff you could have lost! Make sure you don't find yourself in that situation again and start making offline copies of your important things.

Comment: I am not storing backups of my drives on windows, does windows stores back up by default?